# Keeping WPF Margins with nested controls when re-sizing window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm newer to WPF and I'm having some issues with re-sizing the main window. The way I have it set up is I have one .xaml file called MainMapTab that is basically just DockPanel with a canvas inside. In the MainMapTab.xaml.cs file we have the below code.

```
public partial class MainMapTab : UserControl
{
    public MainMapTab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(AddMapKey));
    }

    [Dependency]
    public IUnityContainer UnityContainer { get; set; }

    public MainTabPanel MainTabPanel { get; set; }

    private void AddMapKey()
    {
        var myControl = UnityContainer.Resolve<MapKey>();
        myControl.MainMapTab = this;

        Canvas.SetLeft(myControl, Map.ActualWidth - 525);

        Map.Children.Add(myControl);
    }
}
```

On the initial load of the Main Map Tab, the child control is perfectly situated. But on resize of the main window the child control stays in the initial position, so it has a huge waste of space. What I want to do is have it stick in the upper right hand corner of the Main Map Tab, but while keeping the canvas on the Main Map Tab still being able to be edited in the future. The goal is to have another control added to that canvas and allow the user to click and drag them around. I think the issue is with the Canvas.SetLeft method call, but I'm not sure what an alternative would be.

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `Canvas`.  It is not an appropiate container for what you want. See [WPF Layouts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start). Also, you shouldn't be  composing UI elements like this, instead use the [WPF Content Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb613548(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks @HighCore I appreciate the feedback. For allowing the user to drag icons around on the Main Tab screen and place them wherever they want to, would a stack panel be the better solution? And I'll have to research the WPF Content Model some more to understand how it's used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to a Stack Panel instead of the Canvas that was suggested fixed the re-sizing issue. There may still be an issue with clicking and dragging UI elements on this window. But it might be possible to address it with a nested canvas inside of the Stack Panel.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Canvas.SetRight` instead of `Canvas.SetLeft`?

Comment: Yeah I tried that as on option. It moved the control to the middle(ish) of the window with the same static positioning issue, just in a different spot.

Comment: What I've discovered so far, by using a Stack Panel I'm able to give the nested control a static right and top margin, so it will always be that given distance from those two sides so it will move as required.